# How to reproduce Matrix digital rain freezing symbols effect?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to make a matrix rain app. I want different arrays to move at different speeds, but I can't solve the effect of freezing symbols (when a symbol from the array stays at its previous Y coordinate while the array continues to move down). When the speed of the array doesn't match the font size it starts to twitch while moving. My headache lines are these two

```
int charIndex = Math.abs((i - s.posY) % s.text.length);
g2d.drawString(s.text[charIndex], s.posX, s.posY - (i * FONT_SIZE));
```

I know I need to compensate for font-size and speed offset but I can't figure it out

```
public class TextDrops extends JPanel
{
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1400;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 700;
    private static final int FONT_SIZE = 14;
    private static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 30;
    private static final int SPEED_MIN = 5; // 5
    private static final int SPEED_MAX = 20; // 20

    private List<Streamer> listStreamers;

    public TextDrops() {
        listStreamers = new ArrayList<>();
        populateList();
    }

    public void populateList() {
        int maxStreamers = 200;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxStreamers; i++) {
            Streamer s = new Streamer();
            listStreamers.add(prepareStreamer(s));
        }
    }

    public Streamer prepareStreamer(Streamer s) {
        // pick random x-coord for a rain drop
        s.posX = new Random().nextInt(SCREEN_WIDTH / FONT_SIZE) * FONT_SIZE;
        s.posY = 0;
        s.speed = new Random().nextInt(SPEED_MAX) + SPEED_MIN;

        s.text = new String[] {
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
            "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
        };

        return s;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (Streamer s : listStreamers) {

            s.posY += s.speed;

            for (int i = 0; i < s.text.length; i++) {
                // trying to emulate the freezing symbols effect here 
                int charIndex = Math.abs((i - s.posY) % s.text.length);

                // draw frame
                g2d.drawString(s.text[charIndex], s.posX, s.posY - (i * FONT_SIZE));
            }

            // reset text drop as soon as its tail reaches the end of the screen
            if (s.posY - (s.text.length * FONT_SIZE) >= SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
                prepareStreamer(s);
            }
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_MILLIS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public static class Streamer
    {
        private int posX;
        private int posY;
        private int speed;
        private String[] text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextDrops());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've run your code but I can't see the issue you describe, apart from filckering.  I suspect that you are moving the text trains with pixel (sub character) accuracy, which will not work. In the effect, the characters don't move at all. (Depending on which movie) so I'd make the columns static with a long string of spaces to fill from the top to bottom and move the trains by replacing the spaces with characters, and the other end with spaces (or the same character with the background colour character)

Comment: Yes, that's probably the issue. My runtime shows symbols changing erratically when the column is moving down, which is not what I want. That doesn't happen when the font size and speed are equal. The other thing is that as soon as I change the line and divide y-cord by font size in the line `int charIndex = Math.abs((i - (s.posY / FONT_SIZE)) % s.text.length);` the flickering seems to partially go away, so I guess I need to compensate for the speed and font size somehow. But I can't figure out the expression.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

Comment: Abra, thank you. Unfortunately, Im really confused with how to calculate that thing

Comment: In your method `paint(Graphics g)`: Try `FontMetrics fm = `[g.getFontMetrics()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getFontMetrics--) and then: `fm.`[getHeight()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getHeight--) By the way, have you read [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) ?

Comment: Abra, but how exactly to apply getHeight() to my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved the problem. Each stream generates a new array of different length every time it reappears at the top and this works better than trying to apply different speeds. So I took speed value away, and used font size to move streams.

[image]